# Angularjs Permissions user types

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building an AngularJS application. In the backoffice of the application, depending of the type of user/account (admin, premium, free) the user will have different permissions (2 types).

1. The *restricted area* (ex: sidebar) is visible, but if a user clicks on one of the links, it will open a modal that says something like "buy the premium version".
2. The restricted area is invisible.

I am thinking of using a combination of services and directives to be applied in elements, but I am not really sure the best path to take, since I would like a feature that could be expanded later on.

I hope someone will be able to give me some advice on how to achieve my goals.

Dashboard layout example:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the user data stored somewhere in a service or controller.  I'd drive all the visibility simply by using `ng-if`

```
<restricted-content ng-if="vc.user.isPremium">
```

No need to create additional directives there.

As for the sidebar content.  If you go the directive route, I'd recommend doing something with a directive that has the following:

- higher directive priority than default
- listens for the click event on the element whereby:

  - if the user's permissions check out do nothing, otherwise
  - call `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` then
  - use a service to launch your "sign up for premium" modal

pseudo code:

```
.directive( 'premiumContent', [
     'popupService',
     'sessionService',
     function( popupService, sessionService ){

          return {
              restrict: 'A',
              priority: -1,
              link: function( $scope, elem, attrs ){

                   elem.on( 'click', function( evt ){
                        if ( !sessionService.user.isPremium )
                        {
                             evt.preventDefault()
                             evt.stopImmediatePropagation()

                             $scope.$apply( function(){
                                  popupService.show( ... )
                             })
                        }
                   }
              }
          }
     }
])
```

implementation:

```
 <sidebar-content-item  ng-click="vc.contentClick()"  premium-content>
```

Here is an example (coffeescript + jade) - http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/qNooZj?editors=1010

Comment: First thanks for your comment, im just having a issue,  regarding with the ng-If, basically i made  service where i store the data about the user information, in my controller i injected the service where than i will check if the user isPremium from the service , but than i have a problem, its taking some time when the page loads,  the sidebar appearing is taking to long time , it gets like blank, when other elements of the pages is already loaded and than it appears the sidebar after some time, i feel is taking too long, here is my code example - http://pastebin.com/u8Wn4VZd

Comment: Most apps have a pre-check before showing any UI, that's the route I'd take.  Get all the necessary information up front and THEN show the UI how it should.  If you're using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router, each state provides a `resolve` property where you can ensure things have been resolved before the template gets loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, one last question, i implemented the directive, but the `code`evt.preventDefault()
                    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();`code` , maybe this isnt working because the action that is being taken is in the popup modal and is being made by using ngClick.

Comment: I was under the impression that the premium-locked content was what you were trying to click, then after click the popup indicating they need to sign up would launch.  Maybe I missed something.

Comment: I made an edit on the answer.  I think the priority was wrong.  It should be lower. Also I added a link to an example codepen

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to define a `currentUser` service which hold the information for current user in your application, when user is not logged in this service has a method like `isAnonymous()` which returns `true` if user is not logged in your application, and also this service might have other properties like `isPremium` or `isAdmin`, if you expose the `currentUser` in your view you can easily filter any part of your view depending on the state of user logged in your application.

You can also check this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62RvRQuMVyg) at the beginning they introduce some neat ways to deal with authorization/authentication.

Hope it helps !